# ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I've searched and find out this may be a problem concerning types. But I tried to force the array to float using astype didn't work out. This must be a simple error, however im a beginner.
About the problem: im trying to form the spatial correlation matrix bewteen the signals of all mics.

```
 R_a[k][l] = np.correlate(self.mic_list[k].delayed_signal,self.mic_list[l].delayed_signal)
```

where this class has a mic_list which is a list of mic, which is another class that has this method

```
def add_delayed_signal (self, delayed_signal):
    self.delayed_signal = delayed_signal
```

Thanks you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `R_a` is a 2-dimensional array. What [`np.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) does is to compute the [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) between two signals, and gives you a vector as a result (not a scalar).

What you're looking for is probably [`np.cov`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) or [`np.corrcoef`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html). These are also vectorized approaches to getting the result you want.

For example:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(10)
>>> y = np.random.randn(10)
>>> X = np.vstack((x, y))
>>> X
array([[ 1.45841294, -0.16430013, -0.20782822,  0.08979425, -1.38337166,
         0.36488053, -2.57135737,  0.81215918, -0.54081983,  0.30421112],
       [-0.79416305,  1.14511318, -0.4962483 , -0.42647021, -0.59925241,
        -0.45612051, -0.02566026, -1.7668091 , -1.63098627,  0.3761437 ]])
>>> np.cov(X)    
array([[ 1.28563113, -0.20563105],
       [-0.20563105,  0.74178773]])
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I read that without passing any arguments extra, it ll be a array with one element, so I tried to pick up using [0] but I keep with the same error
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html

Comment: @R.Baptista Yes, you can try picking up the middle entry. But you're wasting a lot of computational effort. Did you try using `np.cov` or `np.corrcoef`?

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answers!